# Mongo stuck on save

Tags: mongodb

We have a single node of Mongo holding data in a single collection. We run it on windows 2008 64-bit machine with 128 GB RAM. The size of the collection is ~2TB holding ~200M items. Lately, when we save new data to this collection, the save operation take lots of time and after a while get stuck. When it happens, we restart the mongod service and it cause the application to work for couple of minutes, but then it get stuck again.

I don't see any locks in the dashboard, but I see operations which are "active" and "waiting" (they are actually stuck) There are also read operations (~100 qps) which we have on this collection.

Is there a limitation on Mongo size on windows? Any other suggestions what's wrong?

**Edit:**
When I query for currentOp() I see a lot of update operations waiting for the write lock. Those are the ~160 stuck writes seen in the MMS dashboard.
When I query for indexCounters in serverStatus  I see a note: "not supported on this platfrom". I don't see any errors in the event viewer. I don't see anything useful in Mongo logs.

Here is some information gathered from MMS, showing a state in which all 164 writers are stuck waiting for the global Q, they are stuck for days now.

[image]

Comment: I cant see the image clearly. Did you get any locks or index missing?

Comment: No locks , how can I check for missing index?

Comment: How many indexes do you have on the collection that is having issues? Too many might not be a problem at first, but as the collection grows you could hit a tipping point where inserts/updates start running slow.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your screenshot to diagnose a performance issue and practically, this sort of discussion is beyond the scope of what can easily be answered via StackExchange. A good source of information would be the log files as well as the output of `db.currentOp()`. Asya's presentation on [Diagnostics & Debugging](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/diagnostics-and-debugging) provides some helpful case studies & tips if you want to drill down into this info a bit yourself.

Comment: Since you're running MongoDB 2.0.6 (released June-2012) an obvious starting recommendation would be to upgrade to the latest production release (currently 2.6.4) as there have been significant improvements in performance and concurrency in the past few years. The [maximum data size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Data-Size) on Windows with journaling enabled is 4TB, however 2TB sounds like a suspicious limit (eg. [2TB limit for drives partitioned with MBR scheme](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581408)).

Comment: How large is your hard drive? Have you checked the Windows Event log or MongoDB logs for any unusual errors?

Comment: From db.serverStatus() check the indexCounters section for missing indexes. I strongly agree with the upgrade, you should at least go to version 2.4.6 . Try to create a test collection and insert there data, if your server still crash then the issue is with the product, else the issue will be with the collection size.

Comment: @Stennie, Drive size if 3.25 TB currently uses 2.15 TB , I will check but I don't think that's the problem. Thanks